# Php Join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, store

I have two tables

Table 1 category

```
Id    name      img   
1   appliances   
2   books
```

Table 2 products

```
ID  name des  price  cataegory sub  img
1  TV    lcd  125     1        tv
```

I am trying to join the two tables that in category in table 2 ill get the name from table 1

That it will show as

```
ID  name des  price  cataegory sub  img
1  TV    lcd  125  appliances    tv
```

this is my code

```
    $sql = "SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name,
                   p.sub
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on products p = c.id
            ORDER by p.id
            ";

    if($query =  mysql_query($sql) or die())
    {
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {   echo "<tr id='id'>";
            //echo "<td>".$result['img']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['description']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['category']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['sub']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }       ";
```

Comment: you mean: SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name,
                   p.sub
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on p.cataegory = c.id
            ORDER by p.id ?

Comment: Yes Bojan thats what i mean

Comment: learn about joins Shlomo, this is basic one.

Comment: i thought i knew it seems i have to look at it over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM products p
        JOIN category c on products p = c.id
```

It should be `ON p.id = c.id` or what the matching param is i.e. `p.cataegory = c.id`

Comment: but now i get   appliances 32"" LCD LG 400 appliances Tv's

Comment: it's because the relation is cataegory=id, if I trust in the example of your post.

Comment: thats my code so what do i need to change

Comment: already mentioned in my answer - `ON p.category = c.id`. (or `cataegory`, because in the table example you've shown as `cataegory`)

Comment: so what should my code be then?

Comment: omg, just change the ON clause. It's not a code builder site. Make some effort to learn what's been said. Better take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Ok got it finally had something extra there tys for all the help